# Sed, помощь в составлении команды

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

Всем привет, нужно поправить много nginx конфигов. Помогите составить правильную команду в sed, делающую это.

Начальный конфиг:

```
location /blog {
        proxy_pass http://www.blogplatform.com/blogfirst/;
    }
```

Его нужно привести к виду:

```
location /blog {
        rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blogfirst/$1 break;
        proxy_pass $scheme://www.blogplatform.com;
    }
```

1. В строке `proxy_pass http://www.blogplatform.com/blogfirst/;` `http` заменить на `$scheme`
2. В этой же строке вырезать `/blogfirst/` и сохранить, оставив `proxy_pass $scheme://www.blogplatform.com;`
3. Добавить строку `rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blogfirst/$1 break;` после строки `location /blog {`, `/blogfirst/` подставить из захваченной области в пункте 2.

Я остановился на 2 пункте, не знаю как сохранить в область удержания sed некоторую часть строки, но не всю строку. 
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: используйте скобки для группировки символов и `\цифра` для подстановки значения группы: `s/\(выражение\)/\1\1/`

Comment: Это изменение уходит в поток вывода, но не попадает в область удержания (hold space), где её нужно сохранить чтобы затем подставить на третьем шаге.

Comment: Если я не прав можете показать пример команды?

Answer (score 1):

Немного хаки вышло, но работает. Поиграйтесь с патернами по желанию.

```
~$ cat so.test
location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://www.blogplatform.com/blogfirst/;
    }
```

Сам скрип:

```
~$ cat so.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

NGINX_CONF="$1"

[ -e "$NGINX_CONF" ] &&
    {
        tail_re="$(grep -oP '(?<=blogplatform\.com).+(?=\;$)' $NGINX_CONF | sed 's/\//\\\//g')"

        sed -e "s/http:/\$scheme:/" \
            -e "/location \/blog/a rewrite \^\/blog\(\.\*\) HOLDER\$\1 break\;" \
            -e "s/rm\.com.*/rm\.com\;/g" \
            "$NGINX_CONF" \
           | sed -e "s/HOLDER/$tail_re/g"  > "${NGINX_CONF}_new";
    }
```

И после пробега получим:

```
~$ ./so.sh so.test
~$ cat so.test_new
location /blog {
rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blogfirst/$1 break;
    proxy_pass $scheme://www.blogplatform.com;
}
```

**Пояснения**

Можно было бы написать полностью на sed скрипте, но количество экранирования
разъело бы глаза :).

Переменная *$tail_re* вырывает патрен, который потом заменит *HOLDER*.

(?<=PATTERN).* - вернуть все после найденного патерна

.*(?=PATTERN)  - вернуть все до найденного патерна

**Ссылки**

- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-sed.org
- http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html